# $f(x)=x^{p^n}-b$ is irreducible

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $E$ a field, $b\in{E-E^p}$ and $\operatorname{char}(K)=p$, prove that
>   $f(x)=x^{p^n}-b$ is irreducible.

I know that if $b\in{E-E^p}$ then there is no $a\in{E}$ such that $b=a^p$, also $x^p-b$ is irreducible in $E[x]$.

I also know that there is an $\alpha$ in some extension of $E$ such that $\alpha^p=b$, but I do not know if this helps me solve the problem.

I would appreciate your help with this exercise

Comment: @idk Thanks, I have already edited my question

Comment: You should rather pick an extension with an $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^{p^n} = b$

Comment: @Max Ok, I pick an extension such that $\alpha^{p^n}=b$ then $x^{p^n}-b=x^{p^n}-\alpha^{p^n}=(x-\alpha)^{p^n}$... and so?

Comment: Well what happens if the polynomial wasn't irreducible ?

Comment: @Max If the polynomial wasn't irreducible then exist $g(x),h(x)$ such that $f(x)=x^{p^n}-b=(x-\alpha)^{p^n}=g(x)h(x)$ ergo $g(x)=(x-\alpha)^i$ and $h(x)=(x-\alpha)^j$ with $i+j=p^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be a field extension of $E$ where $b$ has a $p^n$th root $a$. In $K$, $X^{p^n} - b = (X-a)^{p^n}$

If $X^{p^n}-b = FG$, $F,G\in E[X]$, then $F=(X-a)^i, G = (X-a)^j$, $i,j<p^n$, then for instance $i=sp^k$ with $k<n$ and $s\land p = 1$.

Then $F=(X^{p^k} - a^{p^k})^s$. Expand this polynomial and look at the coefficient of the monomial of degree $s-1$: it's $-sa^{p^k}$. But $F\in E[X]$, so $sap^k \in E$. But $s$ is an integer, so it's also in $E$; moreover, since $s\land p =1$, it's invertible in $E$; so that $a^{p^k} \in E$. But since $k<n$ and $a^{p^n} = b$, this contradicts $b\notin E^p$.

So $X^{p^n}-b$ is irreducible